# selenium search context is null

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentando reducir código a la hora de llamar a los/el objeto/s usando el driver de Selenium.
Me está dando un nullPointerException a la hora de llamar al primer método del objeto.
Os paso el código por si me podéis ayudar.
Esta es la llamada del test - ejecución

```
    public class Test1 extends BaseTest{
 PantallaPrincipal_SingIn pgSign =  new PantallaPrincipal_SingIn(driver); 
    @Test(description = "encontrar las imagenes sin atributo alt", enabled = true, priority = 1)
    public void PrimerFlujo() {
    //  pgSign =  new PantallaPrincipal_SingIn(driver);
        
        pgSign.getImgAlt();

    }

}
```

Aquí está el Page Objetc donde llamo al objeto

```
public class PantallaPrincipal_SingIn extends Locations {
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    public PantallaPrincipal_SingIn(WebDriver remoteDriver) {
        this.driver = remoteDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //lista de imagenes sin el atributo alt
    public void getImgAlt() {
        Acesibilidad.getListImgAlt(img);
    }
}
```

La parte de extends, no tiene importancia son identificadores y llamadas de webdriver.
Aquí está el error:

> FAILED: PrimerFlujo
> encontrar las imagenes sin atributo alt
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElements(DefaultElementLocator.java:85)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementListHandler.invoke(LocatingElementListHandler.java:36)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy11.iterator(Unknown Source)
> at util.Acesibilidad.getListImgAlt(Acesibilidad.java:23)
> at prueba1.Accesibilidad.PO.PantallaPrincipal_SingIn.getImgAlt(PantallaPrincipal_SingIn.java:29)
> at prueba1.Accesibilidad.Test.Test1.PrimerFlujo(Test1.java:16)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTe**stNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado su error es por que en el contructor por alguna razon no esta inicializando su variable driver, lo cual al momento de hacer la accion viene nulo.

Recomiendo hacer una funcion que retorne driver en la clase que hacer el levantamiento navegador y inicialices tu driver tu clase page.

Te invito a revisar la siguiente documentacion: https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html